# AWS S3 get corrupted image

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I need to create smaller version of image from S3. When I call datastorage via s3.getObject I receive corrupted image file, but In S3 it is saved corretly.
[corrupted image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlXg4.jpg)

I tried to use s3.getObject and set await whenever I can. Also I saving receive image localy to check it before modifing it with sharp. Its a problem with sending image between S3 and my app.

```js
export const s3Config: S3.ClientConfiguration = {
  accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
  secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
  region: process.env.AWS_DEFAULT_REGION,
};

async downloader(url: string)
  {
    const pathParts: string[] = url.split('/');
    const imageParts: string[] = pathParts[5].split('.');
    const path = pathParts[4].concat('/',pathParts[5]);
    const name: string = imageParts[0];
    const nameSmall = name + '_small.' + imageParts[imageParts.length -1];
    const test = name + '_test.' + imageParts[imageParts.length -1];
    this.logger.info(`Image path: ${path}`);
    AWS.config.update(s3Config);
    const s3 = new AWS.S3();
    await s3.getObject(
      {
        Bucket: mediaBucket, Key:path
      },
      function (error, data) {
        if (error != null) {
          console.log("Failed to retrieve an object: " + error);
        } else {
          console.log("Loaded " + data.ContentLength + " bytes");
        }
      }
    )
    .promise()
    .then(async data =>{
      await fs.createWriteStream('./images/'+test).write(data.Body as any);
      // tslint:disable-next-line
    await sharp(data.Body as any).resize(100).toFile('./images/'+nameSmall, (err,info)=> {
      this.logger.info('err: ', err);
      this.logger.info('info: ', info);
    });
  })
  }
```

I expect right to receive image inn correct form, but the actual output is damage.

Comment: No need to deal with file *streams* here, just `await new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => fs.writeFile('./images/'+test, data.Body as any, err => err ? reject(err) : resolve()))`. Let me know how you get on, and I'll post an answer if this works.

Comment: I tried to use your part of code, but still I receive damaged image from S3